# IE11 specific : If modal popup closed - attach callback event to operate on parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, window, popupwindow

I'm opening a modal dialog. As soon as i open the modal dialog i will mask the parent window so that none of the click events can be done on the parent window.

But however, i will need to clear the mask once the child window is closed.

Below is the piece of code which will open the dialog and return the opened window reference.

```
this.contentWindow = openDialog(this.url);
```

Once i open the content window, i will apply mask on the parent window as below : Till here all is well :)

```
this.parentWindow.jQuery("div#layerOverlay").css('display', 'block');
```

But, also i need to register a call back event on the contentwindow when it's closed

```
this.contentWindow.onunload = function () { restoreIEMask(); };

function restoreIEMask() {
    getTopWindow().jQuery("div#layerOverlay").css('display', 'none');
}
```

The above piece of code works fine in other browsers except in IE11. I tried various ways in attaching the callback on the contentwindow iframe etc. But nothing seems to work.

Can some please suggest how to get out of this situation.

Comment: Need some inputs real quick.. Nothing striking to my mind!

Comment: Have you tried to use `onclose` event?

Comment: Yes i did, but it didn't work..